# check if Document exist in a collection failed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, document

I'm trying to check if my collection has a document by a function

this is the function:

```
  @override
  Future<bool> exist(String uid) async {
    final snapShot = await collectionRef.doc(uid).get();
    if (snapShot.exists){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

the result is : Instance of 'Future'  ,, (neither True nor false)

pointing that my function into Provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is fine, you probably aren't awaiting it when calling it elsewhere.

Also, a slight improvement would be to just `return snapShot.exists` instead of the `if(exists) return true, else false`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a future when you call this method like

```
bool something = exist("someId");
```

Will throw an error saying its an instance of future.

But if you await to get a return you should get a bool

```dart
bool something = await exist("someId");
```

To check it in a condition

```
void checkSomething() async{
 if(await exist("someId") == true)
 {
 }
}


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


when quick fix to code M I got these


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HpJM.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCpW3.jpg
```

Comment: thanks ,, I want to know how to use it
because when I put it into button it works will m but when try to use it into condition it takes errors

Comment: In condition you have to use it like if(await exist("idHere") == true){}

Comment: my problem is the place that I want to put condition in is doesn't accept async  and got error

Comment: In the method that you use a condition add async to the method. Updated my answer

Comment: You can create a separate async method and setstate